# When will AR core 1.0 be released?

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

When will AR core 1.0 released be released as I have plans of developing AR applications for Android commercially.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a customer support question. See: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score -1):

Feel free to ask this on Google's ARCore GitHub page:
https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/issues

In the meantime, you can consider using my company's product(s):

- [Viro React](https://viromedia.com/viroreact) - which enables AR/VR development for both iOS and Android with the same code base (in React Native/Javascript)
- [Viro Core](https://viromedia.com/virocore) - exposes a SceneKit-like API for Android and integrates with ARCore, Google VR (Cardboard & Daydream), and Gear VR with a Java API.

When ARCore is officially released, we'll update our platform to support that too.